# SetState in Future-function

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, future, setstate

I like to have an autosync for my future function. I tried a setstate but it did not work properly. Do you have an idea? Happy about suggestions.

```
   Future<AlgoliaQuerySnapshot> queryFunc()  async{

   AlgoliaQuery query = algolia.instance.index('groups').setAroundLatLng('51.5078845,7.4702625');
   Future<AlgoliaQuerySnapshot> snap  = query.getObjects();
   return snap;}
```

Comment: use FutureBuilder Widget

Answer (score 1):

This code is an example for how to build a widget that waits for your async code.

```
Widget mywidget = new FutureBuilder(
  future: queryFunc(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<AlgoliaQuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text("not loaded yet");
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        return Text(snapshot.data.foo); // success - build whatever UI elements you need
    }
    return null; 
  });
```

Also read the [official docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Hi Oswin, thanks for your Feedback. But do you have an idea for a SetState? I need the data refresh automatically.

Comment: The futurebuilder is called automatically when the query finishes. Did you try it out?